# Can a non employee be an admin for a LinkedIn company page?

Tags: linkedin

Can someone outside my company be a page admin for a LinkedIn company page?

I work as a Digital Media Consultant and often assist in social media efforts and set up for clients.

I need to be able to edit their LinkedIn profiles. However, I am not official employee and do not necessarily wish to be listed as one.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand, your scenario is supported.

To do this, an existing admin of the company must edit the company and select "**Designated users only**" under Company Pages Admins. Then, he/she can add admins that they are connected to.

See question "How can I add Administrators?" in [this LinkedIn FAQ](http://learn.linkedin.com/company-pages/):

> #### How can I add Administrators?
>
> From the “Overview” tab, click on the dropdown “admin tools” and select “edit”. In “edit” mode, select “Designated users only” and type in the names of the people who should have Administrative rights. Click “Publish” to save.